# backpress after open application from other application

Tags: android, android-intent, browser, intentfilter

I start a browser from my app and on that url there is a button . the action of the button is start a special url that lunch an activity of my application.
and when that activity start, I press back button but appliction is finish.
I don't want close application.
i think  it is The previous application will disappear.
it it right?
What solution do you suggest?

it is my code.

```
        <activity android:name=".IncreaseCredit.IncreaseCreditActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <intent-filter>

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data android:scheme="test" android:host="successpayment"/>
            <data android:scheme="test" android:host="unsuccesspayment"/>

        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

**start browser**

```
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
```

i'm sorry if i can't explain good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my question: I changed the line

```
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

in my manifest to

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```